# URL Rewrite on a WordPress Page Query String

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress site with a custom page comparison that gets a string.

Now it takes:

```
mysite.com/phones/compare/?between=samsung-galaxy-note-3-vs-nokia-lumia-730
```

It needs to be like that:

```
mysite.com/phones/compare/samsung-galaxy-note-3-vs-nokia-lumia-730
```

I've tried adding code on my site's .htaccess that didn't worked for me and went to WordPress 404 page:

```
RewriteRule ^phones/compare/(.+?)/?$ phones/compare/?between=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also I need to redirect to the new search engine friendly URL too when user gets to mysite.com/phones/compare/?between= URL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting a 404 page because WordPress internally doesn't understand how to handle the URL. So the solution you are looking for will be a combination of .htaccess (for the redirection) plus a rewrite rule so that WordPress can handle the URL

Add the following to functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_custom_rewrite' );

function init_custom_rewrite() {

        add_rewrite_rule(        
            '^phones/compare/([^/]*)/?',        
            'index.php?page_id=XXX&between=$matches[1]',        
            'top' );
}
```

Replace `XXX` with the page_id of compare page, flush the rewrite rules by re-saving your permalink structure. Now add a rule to .htaccess for the redirection and that should work.

### EDIT

Add the following code to functions.php to access `between` query var in the page

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1);

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'between'; 
    return $vars;
}
```

And you can then access it using `get_query_var("between")`

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. But now I unable to fetch the requested string which was previously $_GET['between']. No, problem I can get from Server Request URI..? Is there any way to get request value directly?

Comment: Ah, sorry forgot about that. Just a mere mortal me :) . Have updated my code.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have made new qustion here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324962/ if you can, have a look and see if you can help me. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your rules **before** the wordpress rules. The one you have should work as long as it's before any of the wordpress rules, but in order to redirect a request with the query string you need this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+phones/compare/\?between=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /phones/compare/%1? [L,R]
```

Again, the rule that you have plus the one above need to be before all of your wordpress rules.

Comment: I've added but it's redirecting to WordPress 404 page. It should stay on same Comparison page and show the same results