# how to change url like seo friendly in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, seo

My current url is like:

```
abc.com/products/trade-details/?trade_name=napa
```

But I want this url like:

```
abc.com/products/trade-details/napa
```

How to make this in wordpress url to like seo friendly? I check many answer in stackoverflow but no one worked for me.

I tried with this on functions.php

```
  function wpse_283774_rewrite() {
      add_rewrite_rule( '^trade-details/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=trade-details&trade_name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
   }
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_283774_rewrite' );

function wpse_283774_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'trade_name';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_283774_query_vars' );
```

but still not working.

Comment: Hope this will help you. Check this out:
[https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/custom-url-rewrites-for-templates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/custom-url-rewrites-for-templates)

Comment: not working brother @saleh_ahmad

Comment: then try this one, you might have to adjust some parts. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162489/url-rewrite-on-a-wordpress-page-query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162489/url-rewrite-on-a-wordpress-page-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent category "trade-details" and another, child category, "napa" and assign it to the forementioned category, thus you create hierarchy. Afterwards, go to a product/service you serve in Napa, at the RH sidebar of your related product editing page, choose both primary and secondary categories, first goes the parent and click to update. This has to be done on every page.

Check in your dashboard `Settings » Permalinks » Common Settings` and choose the radio button `Custom Structure`. Change the way your WP Posts appear or, optionally, if it suits you, change the Category Base, it's really easy! You can also install the free plugin "Yoast" on WordPress and choose the way your URLs are shown, by clicking from the left-hand menu the option `SEO » Search Appearance` and then the tab `taxonomies`. Find in `taxonomies` the option "Category URLs", you can remove the categories prefix from there (Category URLs on WordPress contain a prefix, usually `/category/`, this feature removes that prefix, for categories only).

I do not have a clear view of your menu structure or what is shown to the end-user, so I try to guess and help as I can. It would be helpful to have the URL as a reference, it would make us understand your thought better.

Comment: `napa` is dynamic value it is changeble with various name and trade-details is a template name

Comment: I believe for SEO purposes you must have unique content, thus create different posts, without duplicating your content and host all of them under a tag, for example use a tag for "trade-details" and create posts (use different slug) with i.e. /Napa,/Papa, /Nasa etc. Then you present the tag like https://mywebsite/trade-details/Napa or https://mywebsite/trade-details/Nasa. Another solution might be through .htaccess like PrestaShop does. For example, in Prestashop images of products are under, let's say httpdocs/img/p/1/2/3/4 but you get dynamicly https://mywesite/1234-tm_home_default/napa.jpg

Comment: Please, check something similar at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664579/url-rewriting-via-wordpress-rewrite-or-htaccess?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use `add_rewrite_tag` function, with `add_rewrite_rule`.